# The object name 'FacetsXrefStaging.Facets.Facets.FacetsXrefImport' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2

Tags: sql

Hi i have created a proc which truncates and reseeds the no of records from the tables. but i am getting the error : The object name 'FacetsXrefStaging.Facets.Facets.FacetsXrefImport' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Create proc TruncateAndReseedFacetsXrefStagingTables
'
'
Declare variables
'
'
            SET @iSeed = ( SELECT   CASE WHEN MAX(FacetsXrefId) IS NULL
                                         THEN -2147483648
                                         ELSE MAX(FacetsXrefId) + 1
                                    END
                           FROM     FacetsXref.Facets.Facets.FacetsXrefCertified
                         )
            TRUNCATE TABLE FacetsXrefStaging.Facets.Facets.FacetsXrefImport
            DBCC CHECKIDENT ('FacetsXrefStaging.Facets.FacetsXrefImport', RESEED,@iSeed )

```
        TRUNCATE TABLE FacetsXrefStaging.Facets.FacetsXrefImport
```

Can anybody help me with that.
I AM USING SQL SERVER 2005.

Comment: Never mind. I got it. it was just a typing error "FacetsXref.Facets.Facets.FacetsXrefCertified "

Comment: You could probably delete your question then.  It's really not adding anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually *having* this problem that the OP had - and there's no typo involved in my situation.  :-)

This is a table that exists on a different server from the server I'm on.  The servers are linked.

The queries above and below the TRUNCATE statement work just fine.
The TRUNCATE does not work.

...Anonymized to protect the innocent...

```
select count(*) as mc from servername.databasename.dbo.tablename -- works
truncate TABLE [servername].[databasename].[dbo].[tablename]     -- error
select count(*) as mc from servername.databasename.dbo.tablename -- works
```

Error message:

```
The object name 'servername.databasename.dbo.' 
contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.
```

[image]

Yes - the TRUNCATE is commented but I noticed that after I did all the blur effects and wasn't going to go back and re-make the image - sorry :-(  - ignore the begin/end tran and the comment markers - the TRUNCATE does not work - see error above.